# What's the difference between various question structures?

Tags: word-order, questions

Is there any difference between these sayings

> Why are you smiling?

and

> Why you are smiling?

Or

> What is your name?

and

> What your name is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. Sentences 1 and 3 are correct, and are used very commonly. They are grammatical. As for sentences 2 and 4, there are grammatically wrong, unless they are part of another sentence, for example,

> "Are you happy? Is that **why you are smiling?**"

and

> 'JimJim'? Is he making fun of you or **is that what your name (actually )is?**"

Comment: I couldn't think of where such word orders would occur in a question.  Good examples!

Answer (score 1):

> You are smiling

is a simple statement. To turn into a closed question (one that requires a "yes/no" answer), you swap the verb and subject:

> Are you smiling?

To ask an open question (one with multiple possible answers), you swap the verb and subject, then put a question-pronoun (why, when, where, to whom etc) where the subject was:

> Why are you smiling?

So, if you don't swap the verb and subject, "why" is a relative pronoun, not question pronoun, so it's not a question. it's not a complete sentence any more because the relative pronoun needs to tie it to something else, like this:

> I know why you are smiling